# Flutter: Problem with Firebase and Navigation

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I use the next simple code for the whole process of login/register:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<FirebaseUser>.value(
      value:  _auth.onAuthStateChanged,
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: Wrapper(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Wrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final firebaseuser = Provider.of<FirebaseUser>(context);

    // return either Home or Authenticate widget:
    if (firebaseuser == null) {
      return WelcomeScreen();
    } else {
      return StreamProvider<MyUser>.value(
        value: FirestoreService(uid: firebaseuser.uid).user,
        child: MaterialApp(
          home: HomeWrapper(),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see I use a second `StreamProvider` for my User model (with user data) which is populated at the same time it is created or logged in:

```
  @override
  Future<MyUser> signUp(String email, String password, Extrainfo info) async {
    try {
      AuthResult result = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
      FirebaseUser firebaseUser = result.user;

      // create a new document for the user with the uid
      FirestoreService().createUser(firebaseUser.uid,email,extrainfo);

      return _userFromFirebaseUser(firebaseUser);
    } catch (e) {
      //print(e.toString());
      //return e.toString();
    }
  }
```

Normally users register/log in the `WelcomeScreen()` and then the second `stream` (of MyUser) triggers the building of `HomeWrapper()` (from where I have all user's data available). Users get redirected here automatically.

**The problem is**: everything works fine **unless I introduce navigation within the `WelcomeScreen()`**. I need to have some screens within it, but once I do that, when registering the screen does not automatically change to `HomeWrapper()` (Although the value of the stream gets called). This does not happen when signing in since onAuthStateChanged gets called and the re-build is triggered higher up in the widget tree.

I guess the problem is that the second Provider is outside the scope of the navigation but I do not know how to fix this in a propper way.

Answer (score 2):

in a proper way, i just suggest you to navigate to the home screen only when the user has been effectively registered; i mean in the SignUpScreen.

when you will call your signUp function: with `then(/*navigation callback*/)` instead of using a stream in your wrapper. just remove it, and try this way.

Comment: Thanks, that's a way arround the problem that I found yesterday and it works. I guess I shoulnt fight the system